# Ionic 4 CORS issue on mobile device

Tags: http, ionic-framework, mobile, cors

I have an Ionic 4 project, where I need to make post and get calls to a server. The server is a spring java server that only allows calls from http://localhost:4200 and runs itself on http://localhost:8080. I have only the DNS address of the Server. The problem is when I deploy the app for a mobile device, it starts a localhost server where CORS in enforced by the [WebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/).


I get this Error:


**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.**

For the Rest Call I use the `HttpClient` from Angular, I already read that the Ionic-Native/HTTP handles CORS issues, but I would need to rewrite all of my calls and I can't test it on the browser, which would take quite some time to develop. Is it possible to handle this problem with a proxy that tells the server that my origin is "http://localhost:4200" or allow on Spring that any IP-Addresses from a specific port are allowed? I have also seen that there is a library called [ionic-native-http-connection-backend](https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend), that uses the native http from ionic when it's possible, but it doesn't work.

I hope there is way where I can use the `HttpClient` from Angular and workaround this problem somehow or if changes in the backend MUST be done that they are minimal.

Thank you for taking your time to help me.

---

This is my CLI and project version:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.12
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.7.5
   @angular/cli                  : 6.1.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.0.0
```

Cordova:

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 7 other plugins)
```

System:

```
   NodeJS : v8.11.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 8.1
```

---

Comment: Without native http plugin you will not able to call api in your app but you can do conditional code to use ur HTTPClient call on browser and native http call on mobile app by this you can able to work your api on both case. Hope you can get my point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, seems like there is no real workaround here. Do you know if I can use the angulat httpclient options in ionic native http as header?

Comment: how did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you might get the benefit of ionic-native-http-connection-backend until the authors have a full release for ionic 4:

Copy the contents of [ionic-native-http-connection-backend/src](https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend/tree/master/src) folder to somewhere under your project’s app/ folder. i.e.: app/ionic-native-http-connection-backend and use it directly. All you have to do is import it into your app module (remove HttpClientModule if you have it in app.module.ts). You don't have to change anything else.

**Sample app.module.ts:**

```
import { HttpBackend, HttpXhrBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NativeHttpModule, NativeHttpBackend, NativeHttpFallback } from 'ionic-native-http-connection-backend';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        NativeHttpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [
        {provide: HttpBackend, useClass: NativeHttpFallback, deps: [Platform, NativeHttpBackend, HttpXhrBackend]},
    ],
})
```

**BONUS TIP:** If you need to by-pass ssl check during your testing, edit the native-http-backend.ts  inside ionic-native-http-connection-backend: and insert: nativeHttp.setSSLCertMode('nocheck');

In my case I inserted the ssl 'nocheck' after line # 141:

**native-http-backend.ts:**

```
this.nativeHttp.setDataSerializer(
    this.detectDataSerializerType(req),
);
this.nativeHttp.setSSLCertMode('nocheck'); // REMOVE FOR PRODUCTION
this.nativeHttp[requestMethod](url, body, { ...headers })
    .then((response: HTTPResponse) => {
        fireResponse({
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the solution that I hoped for. For everyone who doesn't want to rewrite the HttpClient-Requests due to CORS issues, try this out.

Comment: You're welcome! So much confusing and conflicting information overload out there about this...

Comment: Why don't you just install the library? ```npm install --save ionic-native-http-connection-backend@next```. Yo will need to modify *native-http-backend.ts* for your tests in every single clone project buy you'll keep the library updated.

Comment: I implemented this, but get more issues, can you help me how to integrate this? this also works for browsers?

Comment: how would do i use this in my service ts file?